# Sell packs of virtual tokens to user

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

im trying to sell packs of tokens in my website so the users can buy products with them. I created a tokens pack table where i set the tokens quantity and price

```
Schema::create('tokens_packs', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('quantity');
            $table->integer('price');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

I have the add to cart function

```
 public function add_to_cart()
    {

        $tkn = Tokens::find(request()->tkn_id);
        $cartItems = Cart::add([
            'id' => $tkn->id,
            'name' => $tkn->name,
            'qty' => request()->qty,
            'price' => $tkn->price
        ]);
        Cart::associate($cartItems->rowId, 'App\Models\Tokens');
        Session::flash('success', 'Product added to cart.');

        return redirect()->route('cart');
    }
```

But when i submit add to cart it shows the error
`Trying to get property 'id' of non-object`
When i dd the $tkn variable it shows null.
Am i doing something wrong, can you guys give me some ideas

The form that adds to cart

```
 <form action="{{ route('cart.addt') }}" method="post">
                            @csrf
                            <div class="quantity">


                                <input title="Qty" class="email input-text qty text" name="qty" id="qty" type="text" value="{{$token->quantity}}">


                            </div>

                            <input type="hidden" name="pdt_id" value="{{ $token->id }}">

                            <button class="btn btn-medium btn--primary">
                                <span class="text">Add to Cart</span>
```

Comment: So the query `Tokens::find(request()->tkn_id)` doesn't return any match. Are you sure that `request()->tkn_id` contains a valid primary ID that exists in the table the `Tokens`-model uses?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson i change it to ```Tokens::find(request()->id)``` but the same result. The table has records also.

Comment: That doesn't tell us anything. Where does the request actually come from and how is it sent? How is the id passed? Is it using `id` or `tkn_id`? Is it in a POST request? GET request (query string)? Have you check if either `request()->tkn_id` or `request()->id` actually contains anything, or are you just assuming that the value will magically appear?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I will update the code so i can show the forms of how the id is passed.

Comment: Please take a look

Comment: I don't see any inputs with the name  `id` or `tkn_id`. If it's the token id you need, it looks like it's sent as `pdt_id`. In your `add_to_cart()`-method, try using `request()->pdt_id`. Always make sure you use the correct name when fetching data. You should also remember that a user can change that value to pass in anything (never trust user data) so you should check if `$tkn` is null or not before you add stuff to the cart. Don't assume you'll always get the data you expect.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson thank you for the help. Im a beginner and totally forgot the input name, embarrasing mistak

Comment: No worries. It happens to all of us, beginner or not :-)